# How to reduce CSS animation on mouse over?

Tags: css

*This is a very general question, so I have not provided a code.* 

I was trying out various CSS animations yesterday, however, I was unable to control any of them using the `:hover` pseudo element in CSS. I basically wan't to slow the animation when a user brings his/her mouse onto the division.

Pure CSS solution will be appreciated. :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *"comon way"* to do this. You will need to find some workarounds.

The most common workaround to slow a CSS animation down on hover is to  apply the same animation on the element and it's parent and pause one on hover with the `animation-play-state: paused;`. (or the other way around with `animation-play-state: running;`)

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2D3BC/)** (comes from this answer : *[Change the Animation speed on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636549/1811992)*)

As you can imagin this can't work for all animations and you will need to be creative in each situation to find a solution for this.