# How to smoothly revert CSS animation to its current state?

Tags: html, css, animation

I've got *not animated* element as default. There's also a trigger that lets me turn on & off animation on that element. The animation itself is very simple: moves element from left to the right and back.

When I stop animation, then my element obviously goes back to initial position. But it goes back suddenly, not smoothly. So it just changes its position from the one when I turned off animation to initial one. My question is: is there a way to stop it smoothly, so when I turn off the animation it goes back to initial position but smoothly/animating.

Here's my element and animation: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lwftq6r/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="anim">
<label for="anim">Start / stop animation</label>
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div { 
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 50px; height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

#anim:checked ~ div {
    -webkit-animation: dance 2s infinite ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: dance 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dance {
  0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(300px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes dance {
  0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { -moz-transform: translateX(300px); }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the current CSS specs do not make provision for this behavior. There are a few workarounds for this issue (the lack of transitioning back to "ground state" after stopping/removing the animation), but they are all JS-based. Would you consider a JS-based solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smoothly stop CSS keyframe animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668238/smoothly-stop-css-keyframe-animation)

Comment: Has this been solved?

Answer (score 14):

I just had the same problem and I solved it by not using animation and it works perfectly! Check out my solution: 
So I had this spatula that I had to move when hovered over only, and I wanted it to transition back smoothly, so this is what I did:

```
#Spatula:hover{
    animation-direction:alternate;
    transform: translate(1.2cm,1cm);
    transition: all 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;

}

#Spatula{
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is the simplest solution I've seen and it worked for me :)

Comment: `animation-direction:alternate;` is not needed I guess

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately it applies to everything, including if the target element is on a modal and the modal is closed. The element takes 1.5s to disappear...

Comment: this is not very useful if the animation is running more than once, you cannot mimic that with transitions

Answer (score 4):

You can't archive this effect only `CSS3` way, but if you really need it, you could use `jQuery` + `CSS3 Transitions`. My solution (http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/3jouzkxr/10/):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="anim-input">
<label for="anim-input">Start / stop animation</label>
<div class="anim-div"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.anim-div { 
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
}

    .anim-div_active {
        -webkit-animation: moving 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
        animation: moving 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    }

    .anim-div_return {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes moving {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(300px); }
}

@keyframes moving {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(300px); }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#anim-input').on('change', function() {
    var $animDiv = $('.anim-div');
    if (this.checked) {
        $animDiv.removeClass('anim-div_return')
                .addClass('anim-div_active');
        return;
    }

    var transformValue = $animDiv.css('webkitTransform') ||
                         $animDiv.css('transform');
    $animDiv.css({'webkitTransform': transformValue,
                  'transform': transformValue})
            .removeClass('anim-div_active');

    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        $animDiv.addClass('anim-div_return')
                .css({'webkitTransform': 'translateX(0)',
                      'transform': 'translateX(0)'});
    });
});
```

**P.S.**
Vendor prefixes are based on actual browsers list from http://caniuse.com.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an alternate solution, it might not give you the desired effect of going back to it's original state, but since nobody mentioned it and this problem seems to have no solution, it's possible to pause the animation purely in css, locking it's state until it's started again

To pause the animation you need first to make the animation available even when the checkbox is not checked

And make use of the [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) property

```css
div { 
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 50px; height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    animation: dance 2s infinite ease-in-out paused;
}

#anim:checked ~ div {
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes dance {
  0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { transform: translateX(300px); }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="anim">
<label for="anim">Start / stop animation</label>
    
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is such a smart solution and works perfectly. It's not reverting the animation but definitely prevents the jump when not hovering the element anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668238/smoothly-stop-css-keyframe-animation).

> You aren't going to like this answer, but reality is that CSS3
>   animations aren't really useful to achieve this. To make this work you
>   would need to replicate a lot of your CSS in your Javascript which
>   kind of destroys the point (Like for example in this closely related
>   answer
>   [Change speed of animation CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340112/change-speed-of-animation-css3)).
>   To really make it stop smoothly your best bet would be to write the
>   animation on a platform like the [Greensock animation library](http://greensock.com/css3/)
>   which provides all the tools you need to make it actually smoothly
>   stop instead of suddenly stop.

There's also another answer below it that does make an effort at using CSS, you can look at that one.

Comment: On a related note, this is something that is being added to the angular animateCss service.