# How To Make CSS Animations Ease Back To Position When No Longer Hovering?

Tags: css, css-animations

In my example, I'm using ["Bob" by Ian Lunn](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/). I really like the Hover effect, but as soon as I stop hovering it jolts back to it's original position. How can I ease my div back to it's regular position?

**Animation CSS:**

```
animation-name: hvr-bob-float, hvr-bob;
animation-duration: .3s, 1.5s;
animation-delay: 0s, .3s;
animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-direction: normal, alternate;
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/v3z9rLae/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144769/how-to-smoothly-revert-css-animation-to-its-current-state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smoothly stop CSS keyframe animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668238/smoothly-stop-css-keyframe-animation)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - The Answer from "Vals" does appear to solve an issue like mine, but it's not entirely clear (at least to me) what he did in his answer. I'm studying it at the moment and will close this thread as a as soon as I can make sense of his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element to make the circle and animate it with `hvr-bob`.  Then use a transition on its parent to simulate the `hvr-bob-float` animation.  It's not great, but it reduces some of the abruptness.

[Here's an update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3z9rLae/1/)

```css
/* Bob */
     @-webkit-keyframes hvr-bob {
      50% {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
       transform: translateY(4px);
      }
     }
     
     @keyframes hvr-bob {
      50% {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
       transform: translateY(4px);
      }
     }
    
     .hvr-bob {
      display: inline-block;
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            margin: 2%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            
            /* use transition on parent */
            -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
     }
    
        /* the circle using a pseudo-element */
        .hvr-bob:before {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            background-color: #DDDDDD;
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    
        /* use transform on parent */
         .hvr-bob:hover, .hvr-bob:focus, .hvr-bob:active {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
            transform: translateY(-8px);
        }
     
     .hvr-bob:hover:before, .hvr-bob:focus:before, .hvr-bob:active:before {
      -webkit-animation-name: hvr-bob;
      animation-name: hvr-bob;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
      animation-duration: 1.5s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
      animation-delay: .3s;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
      animation-direction: alternate;
     }
```

```html
<div class="hvr-bob"></div>
```